# Error in "For Loop" in Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I am using VBA in Microsoft Excel to code an automatic maze solver. In my code, I want to colour any white cell, that is surrounded by four black cells, black.

My original code was this:

```
For Each cell In Range("A2:AU34")
     If cell.Interior.Color = vbWhite And cell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlack And cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbBlack And cell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlack And cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbBlack Then
          cell.Interior.Color = vbBlack
     End If
Next
```

However, when I tried to run this code, I keep getting "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

When I changed my code to the following, it works.

```
For Each cell In Range("A2:AU34")
     If cell.Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
          If cell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlack And cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbBlack And cell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlack And cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbBlack Then
               cell.Interior.Color = vbBlack
          End If
     End If
Next
```

I tried to ask my professor why this was so, but he too was stumped. To me, both codes are logically equivalent.

Why is it that the first one does not work, but the second one does?

Someone told me that it is most likely due to the fact that VBA does not have short-circuiting. Before anyone links me to a certain post on this community about short-circuiting, I would like to add that I am only taking a small module in VBA as a requirement of my university. I am not majoring in software engineering or computer science and literally 24 hours ago, I knew nuts about coding. I have seen that post on short-circuiting but I still do not understand the concept of short-circuiting.

I apologise in advance if this is a trivial bug and if this is the wrong community to be asking for help on such an issue!

I would appreciate any comments on this! In particular, does my original code not work because VBA does not have short-circuiting? If so, I  hope someone can explain what short-circuiting is as intuitively as possible! Or does my original code not work due to some other problem?

***EDIT 1***: In short, my question (I believe) is why does VBA not know how to execute “IF A AND B AND C AND D AND E” (equivalent to my original code) but know “IF A THEN IF B AND C AND D AND E” (equivalent to my refined code)? Both have multiple ANDs, do they not?

***EDIT 2***: I want my code to test for the fill of the neighbouring cells, given any white cell, within the range. For example, take Cell B3, which is within A2:AU34. If Cell B3 is white, I want it to turn black if and only if Cells B2, C3, B4 and A3 are all black (imagine going in a clockwise direction). Cells outside the range of A2:AU34 do not need to be considered.

Comment: I think that you already have the answer to this: there is no short-circuiting when using 'And' and 'Or'. Therefore, all four parts of your `If` statement are evaluated regardless of whether the first (or second, etc.) are `true`.

Comment: The code you have provided is incomplete.  Please update your code to fully functional code that at least compiles (Debug.Compile Project).   The variable name cell is also a terrible choice for VBA in Excel due to the potential to clash with Cell.  Range("A2:AU34") is unqualified and returns the whole range so that cell becomes the range (Variant/Object/Range).  Your test is therefore testing if the background colour of the range is white if I understand excel correctly.

Comment: @Martin that is the part I do not understand. Why does evaluating all four parts of my IF statement become an issue? Or rather, why does VBA not understand “IF A AND B AND C AND D AND E” but understands “IF A THEN IF B AND C AND D AND E”? I still do not get the logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are learning to code in VBA then there are a number of things you should do

1. Put Option Explicit at the start of each Module/Class/Form
2. Do a Debug.COmpile Project before you try to run your code
3. Install the fantastic and free RUbberDUck Addin.  This addin includes many features missing from the VBA IDE but of significance for the beginner is the much more rigourous static checking done on the Code Inspections Module.  The RubberDuck code inspections trian you to write VBA in a way that is much less prone to subtle errors due to the dreaded 'default' members.

The code you have presented  shows a lack of separating concerns.  i.e. the test for a cell is white and the test for surrounding  cells being black are two separate activities so should not be combined. I'm surprised your professor didn't make this comment.  It is also better to write simpler code and let the compiler do the optimisation so long chains of concatenated logic should be avoided.

Below is the your code above as I would write it.  Please note that I've used ActiveSheet because I'm in a rush.  Normally I'd use a properly qualified sheet referencew.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim myCell As Excel.Range
    ' What is the colour of the cells to the left of column A
    ' your range should specify B2 as a minimum otherwise
    ' you are testing cells that don't exist
    For Each myCell In Range("B2:BU34").Cells

        With myCell.Interior

            If .Color = vbWhite Then
                If SurroundingsAreBlack(myCell) Then
                    .Color = vbBlack
                End If
            End If

        End With

    Next

End Sub


Public Function SurroundingsAreBlack(ByVal ipCellRange As Range) As Boolean

    SurroundingsAreBlack = False

    With ipCellRange

        If Not .Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlack Then Exit Function
        If Not .Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlack Then Exit Function
        If Not .Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbBlack Then Exit Function
        If Not .Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = vbBlack Then Exit Function

    End With

    SurroundingsAreBlack = True

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this. As mentioned, I only have some 12 hours of coding experience in my life. I literally just started learning VBA (and coding) yesterday, so I am trying really hard to digest each line of your answer. I have two questions in response to your answer. Firstly, what is Option Explicit and what is its significance? Secondly, could you also take the time to explain/answer my query in Edit 1?

Comment: @EthanMark You are having problems with your code because you do not understand the Excel object model and hence the logic errors in your code.  e.g. you can't test to the left of column A.  Its nothing to do with short circuiting.  YOu have two challenges here.  Getting an understanding of VBA.  Understanding the object model for Excel.  If your are struggling with the code I provided then your immediate best course of action is to find a VBA tutorial and work your way through that.

Comment: Indeed, the range was the issue! My original code now works just as well as my edited one. Thank you so much for your help. It was really just a minor bug on my end, but I learnt a lot of unexpected things out of this, such as the concept of short-circuiting! Although your code is way beyond my current level of coding ability, I still appreciate it as I can use it to slowly improve my VBA knowledge :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is the color of your Column "A" not white?

cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbBlack

should throw an Exception for Column "A".